# Rails 4 - Grouping ActiveRecord items based on associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails 4 app, where I am making a table that shows me what items I have in stock. Items that are not in stock are **NOT** displayed.

In my controller I do the following:

```
@stock = Stock.all
```

And In my view I have this:

```
<table>
<% @stock.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.id %></td>
        <td><%= item.product.id %></td>
        <td><%= item.product.description %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This is the outcome:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Stock ID | Product ID | Product description |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 1        | 63         | A cool wheel        |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2        | 63         | A cool wheel        |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 3        | 63         | A cool wheel        |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 4        | 26         | A red coat          |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 5        | 26         | A red coat          |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 6        | 99         | Something           |
+---------------------------------------------+
| ...      | ...        | ...                 |
```

But I would like to have it grouped by amount. How could I achieve that?

This is what I would like to get

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Amount   | Product ID | Product description |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 3        | 63         | A cool wheel        |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2        | 26         | A red coat          |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 1        | 99         | Something           |
+---------------------------------------------+
| ...      | ...        | ...                 |
```

I thought this would do it, but it did not work:

```
.count(:all, group: "product_id")
```

Comment: which table contains your amount column??

Comment: No table has it. It is the amount of rows in the Stock table, with the same Product ID

Comment: can you put your model structure here??

Comment: It is really as it looks. `Products` have only a description. `Stock` have only the foreign key to the product they are.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has a `group` function.

How to use it you can find it in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way

```
@stock = Stock.joins(:product).select("count(product_id) as amount,products.id as product_id, products.description as product_description").group("product_id")
```